# Confirm that a message reached the queue

Tags: hornetq

I am using  org.hornetq.api.core.client

how to confirm that sending a message using

```
producer.send("validQueue",clientMessage)
```

was successful and did reached the queue  ?

trying sending to invalid queue i.e

```
producer.send("NoneExistingQueue",clientMessage)
```

did not throw hornetQException as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With core api we allow users to do pure publish subscribe. Not having an address registered means you don't have someone connected to that particular address (i.e. not interested.. on that case messages are just ignored)

If you need that semantic, I suggest you do what we do on our JMS implementation, where we query for existent Queues.

If you know the name of the queue, I suggest you do:

```
QueueQuery query = session.queueQuery(queueName);
```

If you don't know the name of the queue and you have pure pub/sub:

```
BindingQuery queryBinding = session.bindingQuery(SimpleString address)
```

Then you may do the proper treatment for your usecase in case you have no consumers.

Comment: Thanks, so I understand that this is not easy implementation at core api

Comment: No, The core api was meant to pub/sub. if you want to validate if the queue exists you have to use the right method (send a queueQuery or bindingQuery).

You sent a vote up..  you should accept the answer as that probably satisfies your question